# Spring security - Related to SAML

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, saml-2.0

I have a question here. In spring boot 3 series we can use only jakarta.servlet instead of javax.servlet(used in spring boot previous versions). Then how to use 1)SAMLWebSSOProcessingFilter, 2)SAMLAUTHETICATIONPROVIDER,
3)MetadataGeneratorFilter
these classes in spring security as it's import contains javax.servlet

While running application it's throwing class not found exception.

Note : I'm migrating from spring boot 2.7.* to 3.0.* . Using spring security version 6.0.3.

I want solution, how to use these below classes in spring boot 3 series version

1)SAMLWebSSOProcessingFilter, 2)SAMLAUTHETICATIONPROVIDER,

3)MetadataGeneratorFilter

Comment: im facing the same issue, i added `<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>`  in my pom.xml. I still have issue migrating to spring-security 6. Did you face any problem with SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter and SAMLProcessingFilter bean? How did you define authenticationManager()?